# auto increment in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query

```
SELECT 
'MOVERS' AS RECORD_TYPE,                -- Record Type (9)
'PU' AS UPDATE_CODE,                    -- Update Code (2)
M.ADFTHO+REPLICATE(' ', 9 - DATALENGTH(M.SBSNBR)) AS REF_ID,
```

I want all output from the REF_ID to auto increment as follows:
AAAAAAAA1
AAAAAAAA2
AAAAAAAA3 ...etc

How can I write the auto increment in to this query to display the desire result

Comment: Please add a tag indicating the database you are using

Comment: Completely unclear. Provide sample data and the desired output.

Comment: sql 2008 and sample output are as follows: AAAAAAAA1, AAAAAAAA2, AAAAAAAA3, ETC.... THE AAAAAAAA1 is the default but needs to increment by one with output

Comment: What do you want to happen after `AAAAAAA9`?

Comment: What happens when you get to 10?  Do the `A`s aver become `B`s?

Comment: Just don't do this to yourself. Auto incrementing a character like this is fraught with all sort of problems. If you want an auto incrementing number stick with identity. The roll your own versions of this just don't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Condidering `M.SBSNBR` is your auto-increament number column.

```
SELECT   'MOVERS' AS RECORD_TYPE                -- Record Type (9)
        ,'PU' AS UPDATE_CODE                    -- Update Code (2)
        , RIGHT('AAAAAAAAA' + CAST(SBSNBR AS VARCHAR(9)), 9) AS REF_ID
FROM TableName
```

Or if you do not have any auto-increament column in your table, you will need to use ROW_NUMBER() function.

```
SELECT   'MOVERS' AS RECORD_TYPE                -- Record Type (9)
        ,'PU' AS UPDATE_CODE                    -- Update Code (2)
        , RIGHT('AAAAAAAAA' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() 
                      OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn) AS VARCHAR(9)), 9) AS REF_ID
FROM TableName
```